# Mercurial: hg update on pre-existing files

Tags: mercurial

I have uploaded files to a server (CentOS) via FTP. On the laptop, I've been using Mercurial for ages. I'd like to have Mercurial on the server as well, so I can push changes the right way.

I would like to know if the following steps are correct and would not lead to data loss:

1. `hg init` on server (cannot get *server to laptop* to work, so no `hg clone`)
2. `hg push` all revisions to server
3. `hg update` the server to the latest revision
4. Clean up server (commit unversioned files or delete them) and `hg pull` changes to laptop.

I have done steps 1 and 2, but am afraid `hg update` on the server will mess up files which are already there (they should be identical to the laptop, but I can't take chances).

Will `hg update` modify existing files?
Will `hg update` accept existing files that are identical to the repository, or will it create conflicts for them?
Will `hg update` mark inconsistencies as conflicts/added/missing?

I am aware that `hg update -C` does the opposite of what I want. Does that mean it is safe to use without `-C`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It works like that - hg update will possibly generate a bunch of conflicts and possibly restore files you had deleted (not mark them missing). New files have to be added by you (not marked added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're after, you can do it this way:

1. **Back up the directory** on the server!
2. `hg update`
3. Copy the backed-up directory over the repo
4. Do a diff, clean up folder, and commit the changes.

I believe that `hg up` will do what you're asking (keeping your changes, showing merge conflicts, etc.) but why not back it all up first and find out!